# So the collision effect(explosion) doesn't work anymore after changing the player and enemy from SKShapeNode to a .png file

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I changed the custom circular shapes (SKShapeNode *circle) of the player and enemy to a .png file. Before changing the player and enemy to a .png file, there was this explosion effect after collision. However, after changing to .png file, the explosion effect does not happen anymore. Yes, the images bump each other which basically shows that there's collision. But the explosion effect after colliding with each other does not show anymore. How can I implement it again, I need some help please. Thank you very much!

```
#import "GameScene.h"
    #import "CGVector+TC.h"
    #import "ORBMenuScene.h"


enum {
    CollisionPlayer = 1<<1,
    CollisionEnemy = 1<<2,
    };

    @interface GameScene () <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
    @end




@implementation GameScene
{
    BOOL _dead;
    SKNode *_player;
    NSMutableArray *_enemies;

    SKLabelNode *_scoreLabel;


}


-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];


        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;


        _enemies = [NSMutableArray new];


        _player = [SKNode node];
        _player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Player.png"];
        _player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        _player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        _player.physicsBody.mass = 0.2;
        _player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionPlayer;
        _player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionEnemy;
        _player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionEnemy;
        _player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
        _player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        _player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
        _player.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        _player.name = @"Player";
        [_player setScale:1];

        [self addChild:_player];



    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        }

-(void)spawnEnemy
{
    [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Spawn.wav" waitForCompletion:NO]];

    SKNode *enemy = [SKNode node];
    enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Enemy.png"];
    enemy.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionEnemy;
    enemy.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionPlayer;
    enemy.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:6];
    enemy.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionPlayer;
    enemy.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    enemy.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    enemy.name = @"Enemy";
    [enemy setScale:0.5];



    CGFloat x = arc4random() % 70 + self.size.width/2;
    CGFloat y = arc4random() % (int) self.size.height;

    if (arc4random() % 2 == 0)
        x = self.size.width/2 + x;
    else
        x = self.size.width/2 - x;

    enemy.position = CGPointMake(x, y);


    [_enemies addObject:enemy];
    [self addChild:enemy];

    if(!_scoreLabel) {
        _scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Courier-Bold"];

        _scoreLabel.fontSize = 200;
        _scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                           CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
        _scoreLabel.fontColor = [SKColor colorWithHue:0 saturation:0 brightness:1 alpha:0.5];
        [self addChild:_scoreLabel];
    }
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", _enemies.count];

    if (_enemies.count == 18) {
        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                             [SKAction waitForDuration:99999],
                                             [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) onTarget:self],
                                             ]]];
    }
    else {
        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                             [SKAction waitForDuration:1],
                                             [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnEnemy) onTarget:self],
                                             ]]];
    }

}

-(void)dieFrom: (SKNode*)killingEnemy
{
    _dead = YES;

    SKEmitterNode *explosion = [SKEmitterNode orb_emitterNamed:@"Explosion"];
    explosion.position = _player.position;
    [self addChild:explosion];

    [explosion runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"Explosion.wav" waitForCompletion:NO],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            // TODO: Revove these more nicely
            [killingEnemy removeFromParent];

            [_player removeFromParent];
        }],
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.4],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            explosion.particleBirthRate = 0;
            }],
            [SKAction waitForDuration: 1.2],

        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            ORBMenuScene *menu = [[ORBMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:menu transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:0.4]];
        }],
        ]]];

}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

}

-(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [_player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self] duration:.01]];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    CGPoint playerPos = _player.position;

    for(SKNode *enemyNode in _enemies)
    {
        CGPoint enemyPos = enemyNode.position;

        /* Uniform speed: */
        CGVector diff = TCVectorMinus(playerPos, enemyPos);
        CGVector normalized = TCVectorUnit(diff);
        CGVector force = TCVectorMultiply(normalized, 4);

        [enemyNode.physicsBody applyForce:force];

    }

    _player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake (0, 0);

    }
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    if(_dead)
            return;

    [self dieFrom:contact.bodyB.node];
    contact.bodyB.node.physicsBody = nil;

    }

@end
```

Comment: Does did beginContactGet called?

Comment: Hey, i just tried adding a NSLog to my didbeginContact method, and surprised to know that the method is not called when the player and enemy did bump each other. I don't know why. Could you/someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you did not initialize [physicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/physicsBody) before setting its properties.

After creating a player or enemy you should first initialize a body to use. Otherwise it will be nil indicating that the node does not participate in the physics simulation at all. And all property setting will be useless.

This should do for you, dont forget to move that line for the enemy as well!

```
    _player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Player.png"];
    _player.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);

    _player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];

    _player.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    _player.physicsBody.mass = 0.2;
```

Comment: Oh so that's what I missed out. I just rearranged the order and it just made all the difference. Thank you very much.